# MS-Access: Purging a Table of Records Between two Dates

Tags: ms-access

A.) Thanking everyone in advance
B.) Hoping that this Really is a syntactical issue.

I have an MS-Access DB which is processing MONTHLY Downloads.
There is a VBA module which imports an Xlsx data download as a table named say RAW_Data
Subsequent Queries Clean/Normalize this download, then appends to the 'real' table, say Tbl_Data

'Mostly' this Import/Append is new data/transactions every month.
'Sometimes' the Import will include Added/Updated/Corrected data/transactions.
This might include;
new transactions missing from the original download,
corrected/changed transactions from the original download,
transactions deleted from the original download.

It seemed to me that the most simple way to handle this would be to;
Run a Query to calculate the MinOfTranDate and the MaxOfTrandate from Raw_Data
Then run a Query to Delete all transactions in Tbl_Data >=MinOfTranDate and <=MaxOfTranDate
After which I run the standard Append 'New' Transactions Query to replace the deleted records.

But I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I have deliberately NOT included examples of my past (failed) efforts.
Hoping that I am so close that the Query would 'Look' right, but still be wrong.

Many Thanks,

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please read this blog post in order to get better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was as I'd feared.  I must have left out 'something,'

Here's what seemed to work

Set Tmp_Src = DB.OpenRecordset("Qry_Raw_Data_Date_Range")

S_Beg = Tmp_Src("Beg_Date")

S_End = Tmp_Src("End_Date")

Tmp_Qry = "DELETE * FROM Tbl_Data WHERE [TblDate] >= #" & S_Beg & "# And [TblDate] <=#" & S_End & "#"

DB.Execute Tmp_Qry

Thanks for looking,